# Mongoose $lookup populates ObjectId as an array

Tags: mongoose, aggregate

I have 2 schemas, Translation and Facilities.
This is Translation schema:

```
const Translation = mongoose.model('Translation', new Schema({
  az: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  en: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: ''
  },
  ru: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    default: ''
  }
}, { timestamps: true }), "translations");
```

And below one is Facilities Schema:

```
const TourismResourceFacility = mongoose.model('TourismResourceFacility', new Schema({
  name: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Translation",
    required: true
  }
}, { timestamps: true }), "tourism_resource_facilities");
```

Now I need to get the list of matching facilities with pagination and populate name field which is reference to Translation schema. Here is the query:

```
const list = await TourismResourceFacility.aggregate([
                { $match: match }, // this is generated dynamically, so it works as expected
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "translations",
                        localField: "name",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "name"
                    }
                }
            ])
                .sort(sort)
                .skip(_page * _limit)
                .limit(_limit)
                .project('createdAt name.az name.ru name.en');
```

And this is the result:

```
    [
        {
            "_id": "60bf758bf6e70e775a9ab64d",
            "name": [
                {
                    "en": "",
                    "ru": "",
                    "az": "test1"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2021-06-08T13:50:03.136Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60bf740b06ca102d004145ca",
            "name": [
                {
                    "en": "",
                    "ru": "",
                    "az": "test123"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2021-06-08T13:43:39.570Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60bf704c7f55d97090e744f9",
            "name": [
                {
                    "en": "",
                    "ru": "",
                    "az": "test57"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2021-06-08T13:27:40.969Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60bf70127f55d97090e744f7",
            "name": [
                {
                    "en": "",
                    "ru": "",
                    "az": "qwerty"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2021-06-08T13:26:42.149Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60bf128e61f65c7b3f6c04a0",
            "name": [
                {
                    "en": "",
                    "ru": "",
                    "az": "f7"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2021-06-08T06:47:42.531Z"
        }
    ]
```

The problem is that, name field is populated as a list, whereas in the Schema it's ref to ObjectId, not an Array. I need to get the name field as a single Object like {az: "", en: "", ru: ""}, not in a list.

Could anyone help me to create the correct mongoose query, please?

Comment: Why not use mongoose's `populate()`?

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions to it. In case if someone needs it.
{$unwind: "$name"} is the solution, whereas $name is the property name in my mongoose model.

```
const list = await this.model.aggregate([
                { $match: match },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "translations",
                        localField: "name",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "name"
                    }
                },
                { $unwind: "$name" }
            ])
                .sort(sort)
                .skip(_page * _limit)
                .limit(_limit)
                .project('createdAt name.az name.ru name.en');
```